# Freeform Plugin: Success Page and Submission ID - Template not Found

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, freeform

I am getting the following error when redirecting the form success message to a page. I am trying to pass in the submission ID...

```
HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Template not found: contact/success/5015
```

**This is the Return URL**

```
returnUrl: "{{ siteUrl }}contact/success/{{ submission.id }}",
```

I have set up a 'single' entry for the success page - do I need to somehow tie this in with the submission ID?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up a route and assign a template to it?

```
contact/success/{{ number }}
```

Comment: Yes I tried contact/success/{{ submission.id }} but the URI was invalid. I then tried contact/success/{ submission.id } but that didn't work